# How to call a procedure or fire a trigger when a new connection is established in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, triggers

Hi
   i want to call a stored procedure or fire a trigger when a new connection is established in SQL Server 2008.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would a [logon trigger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb326598.aspx) do the trick?